# How to Bring Text to center of the button

Tags: css

**strong text**Hi i am having trouble bringing my text to the middle of the button, tried so many ways but still couldnt figure out way to fix this.
Here is my code;

```html
<div id="liveagent_invite_button" 
      style="display: none;position: fixed; 
       border: 2px solid darkblue; 
       border-radius: 10px;background-color: lightblue; 
       height: 50px; width: 150px;">
   <div style="cursor: pointer; 
           padding: 10px; right: 0px;
           position: absolute; 
           color: darkred; 
           font-weight: bold;"onclick="liveagent.rejectChat('00000000')">
     X
   </div>

   <div style="cursor: pointer; 
         top: 42px; 
         left: 65px; 
         position: absolute;
         font-weight: bold; 
         font-size: 16px;" 
         onclick="liveagent.startChat('00000000')">Chat with us!</div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Add a code snippet here

Answer (score 0):

Hello please try to provide your code to allow us to help you better.

Have you tried text-align: center?